# OWL VIZ error in Protege 4.2

Tags: protege4

I have built my Arabic ontology using Protege 4.2 the latest version published in Protege website,
but when I tried to view VIZ graph using OWL VIZ tab ,it raised the following error

```
TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 195.  Encountered: "\u062a" (1578), after : "\"
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem ? I need to show the Viz Gaph for my Arabic Ontology

Note : the version of GraphViz 2.28

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Fixed it by deleting the existing GraphViz installation (2.30.1) and installing GraphViz 2.26.3.  Make sure you update the location of dot in the GraphViz options in Protege so it will find it in the new location.  After that it worked.

See also 
http://protege-ontology-editor-knowledge-acquisition-system.136.n4.nabble.com/can-t-start-OWLViz-in-Protege-4-1-with-GraphViz-2-30-td4657364.html

Steve

Comment: I have installed the GraphViz 2.26.3 instead of 2.28 , but another 2 problems has raised :  the first one is the tab of owlviz inside preferences was disappeared in which i have to configure dot location , second by pressing owlViz tab in protégé I got the following error : UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file